# Simulate page refresh with CasperJS

Tags: cookies, casperjs, page-refresh, simulate

How can I simulate page refresh (F5) with CasperJS ?

I'm trying to simulate F5 because I want to test if my Cookie Manager works fine ( **the first time must not** set a certain cookie, **the second time it must** ).

Calling two times `casper.start(url)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [`casper.reload`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#reload) is what you are looking for. It will use the underlying PhantomJS function [`page.reload`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/reload.html).